# How to edit manifest file to connect android application to google drive

Tags: android

I have been trying to connect my app to drive using [this tutorial](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart):. This tutorial redirects to this [website](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started): . I got stuck at point 4 where it asks to edit manifest and redirects [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/java-client#set_mime_types_in_the_app_manifest). It seems to me that instructions' aren't clear for the same. Could you please help me out on editing manifest.xml. Thanks.

My manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bignerdranch.android.drive_app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check [this tutorial here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/java-client#set_mime_types_in_the_app_manifest), might help with the values you need to put in your Manifest file.

Comment: Its the same link that I have been asking question about  @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: I though you said you weren't sure what to put in your Manifest file - what help do you need exactly on editing manifest.xml?

Comment: I actually could not understand it. In the given example, there is no .MAIN or LAUNCHER actions. This is confusing me even more. I have an activity file named "MainActivity.java" and the name of the app is app_drive. Could you tell me how would edit my Manifest file?

Comment: Please update your question by pasting your Manifest file - we can examine it and suggest how to adapt it.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I have updated. Please have a look.

Comment: Please have a look at the [Gist with suggested changes to your manifest here](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/8d3e8912fd187878d869566f95651efc) - you can replace your Manifest with it and give it a try.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I am not able to create file as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#creating_files_with_the_createfileactivitybuilder_class. I will let you know when I am done. Thank you so much for your time btw.

Comment: OK, I am glad the Manifest part is done - please give the creating of a file a try and if you encounter problems, please post a separate question with the specific error/problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tutorial that you are following, these are the changes you should make to your Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bignerdranch.android.drive_app" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
          <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=put-yourID-here" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.1234567890" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

By the way, the `data android:mimeType` elements are optional - but perhaps you will need these for the rest of the tutorial.